# R performance issues and interaction with save.image

Tags: performance, r

I observed a surprising performance behavior using R and was wondering whether anyone noticed something similar and would know what causes it. Occasionally my R session becomes very sluggish, any command even very simple operations like `dim(dfm)` [dfm a data.frame] takes seconds. Incidentally I did a `save.image()` operation and the performance returned to normal. I suspected memory leakage or related effects so I tried `gc()` and related commands, with no effect.

I am using R3.01 and RStudio.

Comment: are you using RStudio through a web server?  I've had somewhat related issues when our machine's memory was exhausted and there was a lot of swapping going on.

Comment: `save.image()` is certainly a red herring here, barring a mechanical thing like the "save" operation freeing up a stuck drive head :-) .  Check your free RAM as well as your total CPU usage, in case you've got background processes doing busy stuff.